# Next page icon is highlighted with rounded circle though I am in current page in pagination component of materialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I am using pagination component of materialUI in one of my projects. The issue I am facing is that when I am in current page i.e., 6 as shown in below image with link "pagination issue image". automatically 7th page is highlighted in rounded dark circle as shown in below image "pagination issue image". please help me to avoid highlighting next page(in my case 7th page) in pagination component of material UI

[pagination issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycznS.png)

Below is the code iam using to render pagination component

```
  return (
    <Pagination
      count={totalPages}
      page={currentPage + 1}
      onChange={handlePageChange}
      renderItem={(item) => <PaginationItem {...item} component="button" />}
      disabled={totalPages === 1}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.